# How to return to fetching if the route needs @login_required, after logging the user in

Tags: javascript, django, redirect, fetch

I am building a project using Django as a backend and JavaScript for the client-side, one of the implementation for this project is a like button, sending the data if the user clicked the like button.

```
fetch(`/like/${like.dataset.post_id}`, {
    method: 'PUT'
})
.then(response => {
    if  (response.redirected) {
        window.location.href = response.url; 
        return;
    } else { 
    return response.json()}
})
.then(message => {
    // error do nothing
    if (message.error) {
    // show the error to the user ... 
     console.log(message.error);
    }
    else {
        
        if (message.liked) {
            like.className = "liked like";

        } else {
            like.className = "not-liked like";
        }

        // get the html tag where the number of like is inserted.
        const text = like.parentElement.querySelector('.like-number');

        // then insert the number inside that
        text.innerHTML = message.like;

        // convert the number Ex. 10000 => 10K 
        changeNumber(text);
    }

})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

This is the route where it fetch the data

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def like(request, post_id):

    if request.method != 'PUT':
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Method not found!"}, status=405)

    # Get the post
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    
    # remove the user from the like list
    if post.like.contains(request.user):
        post.like.remove(request.user)
        post.save()
        
        like = post.like.all().count()

        # return message, no of like and boolean expression
        return JsonResponse({"success": f"{request.user} Liked post by { post.user }",
                            "like": like,
                            "liked" : False })

    # add the user into the like list
    else:
        post.like.add(request.user)
        post.save()
        like = post.like.all().count()

        # return message, no of like and boolean expression
        return JsonResponse({"success": f"{request.user} UnLiked post by { post.user }",
                            "like": like,
                            "liked" : True })
```

To like a post a user must login when a user click a like button, it will return a 403 Forbidden with route redirecting the user to login in page, so I handle that at:

```
then(response => {
    if  (response.redirected) {
        window.location.href = response.url;  
        return;
```

That work nicely if the user doesn't login in in the first place it will redirect the user to login page.

In addition to that I want to continue what the fetch start doing, liking the post, and update the number after the user logged in, so that is where I need your help.

Comment: You'll need to add token authentication/session authentication for this kind of action. In your request headers pass a token and verify that token in the backend. If you are not using `djangorestframework` then this may not be possible with the `@login_required` decorator.

Comment: I added a `@csrf_exempt` in Django `views.py` so that is not a problem. What i want allowing a user to like a post after logging in if there are not in the first place.

Comment: How does your frontend know if the user is logged in or not? And how do you tell your backend that the user requesting the URL is authenticated? How do you expect your django app to communicate with JS frontend?

Comment: my frontend doesn't know if a user logged in or not that right, but what a want is this: when a user click a like button JavaScript will fetch necessary data to the backend and the backend, my Django app will return a 403 Forbidden response to the frontend then I redirect the user to login page as I showed in the code above all I want is if there is a way to fetch the previous data ( the post the user liked, …) after logging in the user, If that is possible that what I want to know.

Comment: Like I said earlier, how are you handling the login page in the front end? If you are using the django templates with javascript as fetch, then this shouldn't be a big issue but if you are trying JS framework for frontend then only possible solution here is REST API. See `djangorestframework`.